# Differentiate between threads called by pthread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, linuxthreads

A supplied framework is calling my function `PartialCodec`.

```
pthread_create(&(pcPthread[iTd]),NULL,PartialCodec,(void *)&pcMCData[iTd]);
```

I am not allowed to change the framework code. However, inside `PartialCodec` I want to assign different tasks for different threads and so I need to differentiate between each thread. How can I do this?

Comment: There is no secret here. You have two easy ways of determining what the thread does: One, the `void *(*)(void *)`-argument determines which function the thread starts in, Two, the `void*` determines what the argument to that function will be.

Comment: Every threads automatically goes to PartialCodec function and the argument is same for all the threads

Comment: You are not showing all of your code, but we are assuming `iTd` is different for each thread, which should mean each thread is getting a different pointer to an element of `pcMCData`.

Comment: Why would you do that if you want the threads to do different tasks?

Comment: the final code in this website is basically what I want to do. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/create-threads-in-linux/ but in my case the variable `tid` is not global and so i cant use it. I need a workaround for this

Comment: *Why* do you need to do something like that? Why don't you just pass an appropriate, uniquely identifying argument as the `void*`?

Comment: This is actually part of my project and I have been provided with a set of code which i shouldn't change. I can only write code inside the `PartialCodec` function.

Comment: @RohithReddy: Well, if your codebase comes pre-broken, you obviously won't be able to use an elegant solution. You can always \*shudder\* use a global variable protected by a mutex to pass additional information between the threads if sane means of communication have been sabotaged.

Comment: What @EOF says.  If your task come with ridiculous restrictions applied by your prof, why are you wasting time asking us?   Ask your prof how to do it since s/he is the one causing the problem.

Comment: The only sane apporach is that suggested by @immibis below - make all threads capable of doing all jobs and provide a task ID var in the passed control struct, (maybe an enum), that the thread code can switch on to do the commanded task.

Comment: @MartinJames yeah, I will talk to my professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the argument, Luke.

You're passing `&pcMCData[iTd]` as the thread argument.

So just add some fields to that structure, telling the thread which tasks to work on. (And obviously set those fields before creating the thread)

```
pcMCData[iTd].thingToWorkOn = /* however you decide the thing to work on */;
pthread_create(&(pcPthread[iTd],NULL,PartialCodec,(void *)&pcMCData[iTd]);
```

Comment: This is actually part of my project and I have been provided with a set of code which i shouldn't change. I can only write inside the PartialCodec function.

Comment: So, perhaps it is more accurate to say, "somebody else is launching threads using `pthread_create()`..."

Comment: Yeah, my professor wrote the code for launching threads and I am not supposed to change it.

Comment: @RohithReddy So what information does the launcher give your thread?

Comment: @RohithReddy why are you asking here?  Your prof screwed up the thread framework, so ask your prof how to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how many threads will be calling `PartialCodec`, you can use `static` variables within the function to facilitate communication between threads. A bare `static` would allow all threads in `PartialCodec` to manipulate the same object instance.

```
void * PartialCodec (void *arg) {
    static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    static struct state {
        /* some state */
    } critical;
    struct state local;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    local = critical; /* make a local copy */
    /* update critical */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); 

    /* ... refer to local copy of state ... */
}
```

The `critical` state tracks which part of the problem a particular thread should solve. Copying it to `local` establishes that the thread will work on that part of the problem. The `critical` state is then updated so the next thread that reads `critical` will know to work on a different part of the problem.